# How to remove tag from the data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have one function having data as parameter and that data contains following as value:

```
<a class="result-tooltip" title="" href="/app.php/na_test_na/en/score/view/charted/1/1" data-original-title="<div style=&quot;margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; font-size: medium;&quot;>
<h4>Met: <b>15189</b>
<br>Total: <b>15189</b>
</h4>
</div>">
100.00%
</a>
```

I tried

```
data = data.replace(/<a.*">/, '').replace('</a>', '').trim();
```

But it is not working.

I want only 100.00% from the above. How can I get it?

Comment: why you don't get html or text inside <a> instead of remove tag?

Comment: that value doesn't look like valid HTML. Can you recheck it and post here the exact value of `data` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

If the data value is just a string ( i am not really sure how you pass that to your data variable ) you can make some ' tweaks ' to it.

Create a HTML element with javascript using `document.createElement` , add `data` as it's `innerHTML` then get the `innerText` which would be `100.00%` and assign that value to `data`.

I changed a bit the value of `data` because what you pasted in your question was not valid HTML.

I am sure there must be other ways to achieve this, but this is what i've came out with :)

```js
let data = `<a class="result-tooltip" title="" href="/app.php/na_test_na/en/score/view/charted/1/1" data-original-title="<div style='margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; font-size: medium'>
<h4>Met: <b>15189</b>
<br>Total: <b>15189</b>
</h4>
</div>">
  100.00%
</a>`
const elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.innerHTML = data
data = elem.innerText.trim()
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')`

Comment: It is giving output as 

"
Met: 15189
Total: 15189
"" href=""/app.php/na_test_na/en/score/view/charted/1/1"">              100.00%
"